# AngleSharp - How to browse website whose links trigger form submission

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping, anglesharp

I am trying to scrape the "Read More" links from multiple search result pages of this website: https://www.cgg.com/en/31

There is no canonical link to any particular page of the search results.  When you navigate to page 2, the URL remains https://www.cgg.com/en/31.

Upon inspection of the underlying HTML and JavaScript, I see that the pagination links trigger a JavaScript function when clicked.

```html
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$Layout-7-main-partial2$TmsPager1$ctl02$ctl00','')">NEXT</a>
```

Here is the function that gets called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

So by clicking "NEXT" the browser is redirected to the same URL but with different content.

I'd like to scrape the "Read More" links from the next page after clicking the "NEXT" button.  How would I do this using AngleSharp since clicking the "NEXT" button actually submits a form and reloads the page?

Here's what I have so far: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3f6XZC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible answers here:

1. You need JavaScript (e.g., AngleSharp.JavaScript, which is not available yet for the latest version of AngleSharp) and will need to trigger the form submission by "clicking" the link which fires the JavaScript.

(this one won't work - at least yet - as mentioned)

2. (I guess this is the one you are after - judging from parts of your question) You will need to implement that particular JS in C#. As AngleSharp gives you a dynamic DOM you can do that.

The particular code looks as follows in C# (assuming you also call your `document` instance `document`):

```
Task SubmitForm(IDocument document, string eventTarget, string eventArgument)
{
    var theForm = document.Forms["form1"];

    if (!theForm) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The form cannot be found!");
    }

    void SetElement(string name, string value)
    {
        var element = theForm.Elements[name] as IHtmlInputElement;

        if (element != null)
        {
            element.value = value;
        }
    }

    SetValue("__EVENTTARGET", eventTarget);
    SetValue("__EVENTARGUMENT", eventArgument);
    return theForm.SubmitAsync();
}
```

Hope that helps!